# Can "Log registration No." be synonymous with "Registration No. in the log"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have an official document with a header. 
The header is not fully filled. One cell has a temporary mark:

> Registration No. in the log

When the preparation of this document is finished, the person who finishes the document will make an entry in the log, and create a number for this entry. He will then put this number in the document's header.

I want to make this reminder shorter, because the space is limited in the header. Would "**Log registration No.**" be okay? Or would it mean "the code  under which the log was registered"?

Comment: I think "Log registration no." is fine.  It's using *log* as a noun adjunct or adjectival noun.

Comment: This is more personal practice than "correct" English.  Log Registration # is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: is there a number for the registration and a  umber for the log entry?

Assumptions:
You have a unique number associated with a registration, the *registration number*.
You also entries in a *log*. Are the logs also numbered (as in a ledger book)?
You are using a number in your document header as an index (to be filled in).

If you want the *reference number* itself (the same number written in the log), you can simply use

> registration #

this would be understood to be the same as *Log Registration No.* *(Log's Registration No.)*

If you want the *log entry*, then it should simply be

> log entry #

This is probably what you want since you already have the registration number in the header (somewhere?) since this is already known at the time the form is filled in, you probably want a cross reference between the *registration number* and the *log entry number* in the header (easier to look things up), this would be referred to as

> Registration's Log No.
>   Log No. for Registration

this is because the *log number* is a property of the *Registration* and usually not the other way around since one would first lookup *Registration* and then look for the associated *log entries*.

This is called a *one-to-many* (one or more) in database lingo, since a Registration may have multiple log entries.